# Is there a way to expire the cache of PWA in an angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm developing a website for a retail store in Angular 6 that has new promotions every two weeks. I'm using PWA to prefetch and cache the promotions and images. The issue is when new promotions are added the old ones will still show because it's still cached on the client's side. Is there a way to expire the cache once the new promotions are added?

EDIT: Here is the code in my ngsw-config.json

```
 {
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html"          
        ],
        "versionedFiles":[
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/icons/**",
          "/assets/img/**",
          "/assets/recipes/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code